# Access HTTP PUT data in python hug

Tags: python, api, python-3.x, hug

```
import hug

something = {'foo': 'bar'}

@hug.put('/')
def update_something():
    something['foo'] = <value_of_bar_from_http_put_request>
```

How do I access the put data so that I can update `something`? I looked up [this](https://github.com/timothycrosley/hug) and [this](http://www.hug.rest/website/learn) but couldn't find anything.

Comment: I  have never used this library but according to their documentation it appears that `bar` should be an argument to your function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import hug

something = {'foo': 'bar'}

@hug.put()
def update_something(bar: hug.types.text):
    something['foo'] = bar
    return something  # may be
```

And then you may use requests to test

```
import requests

print(requests.put('http://localhost:8000/update_something',
    data={'bar': 'foobar'}).json())
```